# Understanding Slice of a Set in Product Measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a product space $(\Omega_1\times\Omega_2,F_1\times F_2, P_1\times P_2)$.

Define a slice of a set at $\omega_i$ as, for example: Let $E\in F_1\times F_2.$ For every $\omega_1\in\Omega_1$, we define a slice of a set $E$ at $\omega_1$ as

$$E_{\omega_1}=\{\omega_2:(\omega_1,\omega_2)\in E\}.$$

I would like to understand some "intuition" behind the following measurability statements:

(1) $E_{\omega_1}$ belongs to $F_2$.
(2) For every $F_1\times F_2$-measurable function $f$ and every $\omega_1$, the function $f_{\omega_1}(\omega_2)\equiv f(\omega_1,\omega_2)$ is $F_2$-measurable.
(3) If we let $f_E(\omega_1)\equiv P_2(E_{\omega_1})$, then it is $F_1$-measurable.

So what I did was try to understand (1)-(3) by looking at $(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R})\times B(\mathbb{R}))$ where $E=\{(x,y):f(x,y)\leq c\}$ for some constant $c$ and a continuous function $f$.

(1) I understand this, because if you fix a point $x_1$, it is just the slice under the curve.
(2) I understand this, because what you have is a vertical line, this is naturally $F_2$-measurable.
(3) This is the part I had difficulty. If we measure this vertical line, in the Lebesgue-sense, it is just the vertical line length. But how does this measurement suddenly becomes $F_1$-measurable? What is the idea behind this?

Comment: Anybody can give me help?